# "Task not serialized" Error while calling Function inside mapPartitionsWithIndex in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am New to Scala . I want to call **Function** inside **mapPartitionsWithIndex** . But If I do so then I am getting error "task not serialized". Can anyone having any idea about this.

Error Code :

```
val x = subRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, iter) => mapitr(iter, minusRdd,sc))

def mapitr(value: (Iterator[((Long,Long),(Boolean))]), 
           rdd1: RDD[((Long, Long), Boolean)], 
           sc: SparkContext): Iterator[((Long,Long),(Boolean))] = {
  var x = Iterator[((Long,Long),(Boolean))]() 
  if (value.length > 0) {
    val rdd=sc.parallelize(value.toSeq)
    val substractedRdd=rdd.subtractByKey(rdd1)
    x = substractedRdd.toArray().toIterator
  }
  x      
}
```

My Question is Why I am getting "task not serialized" error In above code or Can I achieve same Thing using any other method.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What is `minusRdd` and `subRdd`?

Comment: `minusRdd` Is RDD of type `RDD[((Long, Long), Boolean)]`. Contains data that I want to `subtract` in `val substractedRdd=rdd.subtractByKey(rdd1)`. `subRdd` contains the complete data which I have partition By index using the function `mapPartitionsWithIndex`.

Comment: Why not do `subRdd.subtractByKey(minusRdd)`? Why create an `RDD` from each partition inside the `RDD`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: where is mapitr defined? inside an object? class? if inside a class is it serializable?

Comment: @AssafMendelson He already has two RDDs though. He's creating an additional RDD from each partition and then subtracting with the `minusRdd`. Seems kind of redundant.

Comment: @Yuval Itazchakov `subRdd.subtractByKey(minusRdd)` This is Possible but size of `subRdd` is huge and `subtractBykey` failed with huge dataset. So I am Partitioning `subRdd` using `mapPartitionsWithIndex` and `subtracting` it part by part.

Comment: Why not repartition the RDD beforehand?

Comment: You Mean I can not call `Function` inside `mapPartitionsWithIndex`.

Comment: Is there any reason to pass SparkContext as an argument to the function? I mean you could define it as class wide val, and use it in the `mapitr` method